# Allow cursor to go past end of file like visualedit=all does for end of line

Tags: vim

I am looking for a way to allow my cursor to move past the end of the file (without adding a whole lot of blank lines in need to delete later) so that when I'm writing a long file I am not always stuck looking at the very bottom edge of my monitor.

What would be perfect is the same behavior I get from `visualedit=all` except for newlines after the file ends instead of spaces after the line ends.

Comment: Fair question, but you don't have to look at the bottom of the screen if you don't want to. `CTRL-E` scrolls the window down a line, and `zt` puts the cursor line at the top. See `:h Q_sc`.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I found `z.` from that help page you mentioned. which basically achieves what I was looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of any possibility to move the cursor past the end of the buffer.

However, if the question is just about adjusting the focus of the viewport, good options are:

- `CTRL-E` and `CTRL-Y` to scroll the window
- `zz` to center the cursor line
- `zt` to put the cursor at the top of the window

More in the 'Scrolling' quickref at `:h Q_sc`.

Comment: I ended up remapping `G` to `Gz.` as I already use G often. Thanks a lot for help